# How do I make a large HTTP(S) request with Python?

Tags: python-2.7, http, request

Edit: I extended the question to HTTPS. The "S" part is not yet solved and I don't really need it, but it might be interesting for others.

I want to do the equivalent of

```
hdr='GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nContent-Length: 10000000000\r\n\r\n'
(echo -en "$hdr"; dd if=/dev/zero bs=1000000 count=999; read tmp) | nc $SOME_IP 80
```

with Python 2.7. If possible, I'd like to use only standard library plus the `requests` and `sockets` modules.

FYI, the above script sends a large HTTP request (~1GB of zeros) to `$SOME_IP` without being to heavy on the senders RAM.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Same thing would be interesting for HTTPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
import socket

def get_content_length():
    return 10000000000

def get_chunk_size():
    return 1000000

def yield_content():
    total_size = get_content_length()
    chunk_size = get_chunk_size()
    current_size = 0
    end = total_size - chunk_size
    chunk = '\x00' * chunk_size
    while current_size < end:
        yield chunk
        current_size += chunk_size
    yield chunk[:total_size - current_size]

s = socket.socket()
s.connect((host, port))
hdr='GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nContent-Length: %s\r\n\r\n' % get_content_length()
s.sendall(hdr)
for chunk in yield_content():
    s.sendall(chunk)
# should I wait for the response?
```

Comment: That's it, thanks. See my answer as to what I cooked up in the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I cooked up and seems to work:

```
import sys, socket

def flood(hostname, port, count=1):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((hostname, port))
    s.sendall('GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nContent-Length: 10000000000\r\n\r\n')
    with open('/dev/zero', 'rb', ) as data:
        for _ in xrange(count):
            s.sendall(data.read(1000000))
    s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
    while True:
        data = s.recv(1024)
        if data == "":
            break
        print("Received:", repr(data))
    print("Connection closed.")
    s.close()
```

The answer by [freakish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/645551/freakish) is of course more cross-plattform, as it does not require `/dev/null`